# Chart in swift have a black background by default

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, charts, ios-charts

I'm using the library [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) for Swift and by default it has a black background.

I just updated to version 3.0.2 and still have a default black background behind my chart. I added a UIView in Storyboard and set the class to `LineChartView`, modules `Charts`, what do I have to do to remove that black background?

I also have tried doing this:

`self.lineChart.backgroundColor = .clear`

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in the `viewDidLoad` function:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```